# How do i force a javascript class to ignore externally added fields in the output

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

** EDITED ** 
For a given javascript function X

```
X=function(obj){
  /* code here */
}
```

How do i modify the function X such that

```
i1=new X({a:1,b:2});
i1.c=3;

console.log(i1) to output as -> {a:1,b:2}
```

thereby ignoring the externally added property 'c'

Comment: You can't do it.

Comment: Do you want to prevent that someone can do `i1.c=3;` or do you want to allow `i1.c=3;` so that `console.log(i1.c)` will show `3`  but hide it in the `console.log(i1)`?

Comment: I am really sorry but can you recheck my post as i edited the question.

Comment: @epascarello It is possible. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use the [Object.preventExtensions()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) method, which blocks the possibility to add new own properties to the object:

```
var X = function() {
  this.a = 1;
  this.b = 2;
  Object.preventExtensions(this);
};

var i1 = new X();
i1.c = 3;

console.log(i1); // prints "{a: 1, b: 2}"
console.log(i1.c); // prints `undefined`
```

Please check this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tocivatodo/edit?js,console) for a complete example.
Notice that adding a new own property to a non-extensible object in `strict mode` can throw a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible if in `es2015` using `proxy`'s [handler.set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set), it's a trap for setting property value, so you can use it to check whether the property about to set is external or not.

Updated to address the request that *expecting the properties to be set via constructor*.

However, it may be more suit to use [Dmitri Pavlutin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36062300/1737627), didn't know that, learned a lesson too.

```js
X = function(props){
  
  // Copy properties if given an input object
  if (attrs instanceof Object) {
    var key;
    for (key in props) {
      if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this[key] = props[key];
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Wrap a proxy.
  return new Proxy(this, {
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
      // Anyway that check if property to set is an external one.
      if (typeof target[property] === 'undefined') {
        console.log("No");
      } else {
        target[property] = value;
      }
      return true;
    }
  })
};

i1=new X({a: 1, b: 2});
i1.c=3;
console.log(i1);

i1.a= 2; 
console.log(i1);
```

Comment: A great answer. Didnt know about it. However I am really sorry but can you recheck my post as i edited the question. I am expecting the properties to be set via constructor. Secondly i dont assume this solution would work for nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override ToString method:

```
X.prototype.toString = function()
{
    return this.a + " " + this.b;
}
```

Comment: This would not work as is since the inner object is assigned properties while it is not initialized.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'a' of undefined(…)`

Comment: You can initialize the inner object as `this.inner = {}`. This would allow you to add properties to the inner object

Comment: yea, sorry - forgot about that. I Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer .However  I am really sorry but can you recheck my post as i edited the question.